# "Access Denied" to the Admin on Old and New Install

Tags: 7, users

There was an access denied issue that I could not get past with my current test drupal install. I installed another drupal instance with a new db and still get this access denied error trying to get into the Admin area. This is not a cpanel, it is a server that is being setup for me.

Does anyone have ideas I can work through to get this resolved?

Does the admin have any special permissions that it needs to "chmod" etc... areas of the drupal site?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you login as an admin. I mean UID = 1 ?
Try to reset the super user password and loggin again.

DRUPAL 6 and below: `UPDATE users SET pass = MD5('givememypasswordback') WHERE uid=1;`
DRUPAL 7 - https://drupal.org/node/1023428

Also check error logs if you think its an internal permission issue.

Comment: Tried what you suggested here. Turns out it was a settings.php issue with the cookie_domain. Issue was, the settings.php wasn't taking my changes, however, the file would upload without any "errors" letting me know that it really didn't get overwritten. Server issue...